# How to produce a $table from two queries (arrays) in PHP, that can be further processed?

Tags: mysql, pdo, php-7

I'm tying to create a dynamic reporting page in PHP using Google Charts.

My approach is to use a PDO/MySQL query sends the output to a script that builds a $table array, converts to JSON and display it.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to build an array that can be used to extract or compare from a specific row, rather than merely having access the sum or average of rows and columns.

Here's a MySQL example of what I'm trying to do:

```
date between date1 and date2 
value of stat1 at [subject] = "14h00 check" (each day between date1 and date2)
SUM($stat2) (each day between date1 and date2)
AVG($stat1) (each day between date1 and date2)
```

Things I've attempted or considered trying, with no success:

- Using SQL JOINS to retrieve the data in a single query.
- Using two separate requests `$req1 (['sum_stat2'],['avg_stat2']) $req2 ([specific_time_value_stat1])`

I've tried doing it with various kinds of loops. For example:

```
for, foreach or while ($i = count($rows_arrays_or_numdays); i++) {
    $var[] = $something->fetch() *or fetchAll or whatever*
}
```

Here's a mockup of the table:

```
|    datetime    |  subject  |event|stat1|stat2|<br>
|1982-13-13 12:03|12h00 check| none| 3725| 6789|<br>
|1982-13-13 12:12|thing #1   |broke| 0028| 0320|<br>
|1982-13-13 12:24|thing #1   |fixed| 0952| 5467|<br>
|1982-13-13 13:04|13h00 check| none| 3568| 1234|<br>
|1982-13-13 13:24|thing #2   | slow| 2300| 0823|<br>
|1982-13-13 14:08|14h00 check| none| 2467| 0912|<br>
```

I'd like to know how to get that into an array that I can convert to JSON for a Google graph, using values from two requests or find some JOIN statement that can reduce the number of steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help clearlight, I will try to follow your guidelines in the future. :)